# How to remove duplicate values in object in forEach

Tags: javascript, angularjs, foreach, duplicates

I have a forEach like this

```
angular.forEach(game.market, function (market) {
  if (availableMarketGroups[market.group_id]) {
      availableMarketGroups[market.group_id].count++;
  }
});
```

I need to check , if availableMarketGroups[market.group_id] number is duplicate , then ignore it !

For example i have id's : a , b , b , b , c , d --> final count is 6

I need also check , if it's duplicated , then ignore it and get final count 4

Comment: I believe you just need to remove the duplicates from your array and then perform your loop. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array

Comment: This is a bit confusing. What object is that your screenshot shows? The one with keys `72799064` and `72799067`?

Comment: .count++; will not work as theres no count var...

Comment: @ScottMarcus data come from swarm , from backend , i can only edit and put it on my html :)

Comment: @acdcjunior this id's is my markets id ,the same is availableMarketGroups -> market

Comment: @Jonasw the count is work , but its show the wrong number , for example i have x numbers , but its show x+y numbers , becouse some  availableMarketGroups[market.group_id] is duplicate

Comment: what is game.market and what is availableMarketGroups? looks like they should be the same but ... it's still very unclear what u are trying to achieve. do you want to remove the duplicates or set a mask for further usage within the DOM?

Comment: @RobinF. Hi and thanks for attention .
Its really big project and something is unclear in this ticket, but , the main mission is , for example 

availableMarketGroups[market.group_id] = 1
availableMarketGroups[market.group_id] = 2
availableMarketGroups[market.group_id] = 3 
availableMarketGroups[market.group_id] = 3
availableMarketGroups[market.group_id] = 3
availableMarketGroups[market.group_id] = 4 
 
In final count i need number 4 (1,2,3,4) not 6 (1,2,3,3,3,4)

Comment: is availableMarketGroups an array containing the amount of groups per group_id?

Comment: I think the overall problem is that it is a sparseArray, making availableMarketGroups.length not work

Comment: From swarm i get random availableMarketGroups[market.group_id] numbers , for example 1 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 3 --> 6 availableMarketGroups[market.group_id], but i want ignore duplicated id's and get from 1 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 3  --> 3 (1,2,3)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a auxiliar structure to store the different group_id.

```
var summedGroupId = [];
angular.forEach(game.market, function (market) {
    if (availableMarketGroups[market.group_id]) {
        if (summedGroupId.indexOf(market.group_id) < 0) {
            availableMarketGroups[market.group_id].count++;
            summedGroupId.push(market.group_id);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: hi , its look like simple and elegant, but count show wrong number again ,

Answer (score 0):

So you want

```
ids=[];
for(key in game.market){
  if(game.market.hasOwnProperty(key)){
       ids.push(game.market[key].group_id);
   }
 }
ids=ids.sort();
uniqueids=ids.filter((el,id)=>(!id||el!=ids[id-1]));
console.log(uniqueids.length);
```

all the ids in a new array, that is sorted and filtered to be unique, and than you can easily check its length.

Comment: its data with this objects:`
72799064
72799067
...

This objects visible in image

Comment: can u create some fiddle or plunk ?

Comment: Its simple of hard to understand , where i must put this? before or in foreach ?

Answer (score 0):

according to your comments i can just guess what you want but availableMarketGroups[market.group_id] means you have the following structure for availableMarketGroups:

```
{ someGroupId: someValue, someGroupId2: someValue2, ...}
```

and it looks like you want the values to be unique and filtered for the currents games's markets. 
(the naming "game.market" does not rly indicate properly that it is actually market"s")

---

**1. approach using reduce**

```
const reducedMarketGroups = availableMarketGroups.reduce((prev, curr) => {
  if (
    game.markets.find(market => market.group_id === curr) && 
    !prev.includes(curr)
  ) prev.push(curr);
  return prev;
}, []);
```

---

**2. approach using a Set**

```
const reducedMarketGroups = [...new Set(
  availableMarketGroups.filter(marketGroup => 
        game.markets.find(market => market.group_id === marketGroup)
  )
)];
```

Comment: Thanks for attention :) Yes , but one think , i need only check it, if availableMarketGroups[market.group_id] duplicate or not , not remove it.